# Axis Bottom-up Webservice IWAB0489E error

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

I am having a look around bottom-up Webservice in Eclipse. Here is my environment:

Eclipse Helios
Java 1.6.0_29
Apache Axis2
Tomcat 6.x

I create Dynamic Web project and create a simple service class. And then I tried to create Webservice for the class, I got some errors like below:

IWAB0489E Error when deploying Web service to Axis runtime
  axis-admin failed with  {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Client The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR) http://localhost:8080/myws/services/AdminService

Searching web, I could not any clear answer yet. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have solved this problem right now. The Eclispe setting Web Services>Server Runtime was 'Apache Axis' not 'Apache Axis2'. So I change it to 'Apache Axis2' and then it works well.

Answer (score 7):

I have the same problem i go Window -> Preferences -> WebServices -> Server and Runtime and set it as you see here:

Previously it was selected Tomcat 6 (i use 7) and axis1 not 2
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try these 3 methods

1) try deleting the .snap file found in

```
yourprojectworkspace\ .metadata\ .plugins\ org.eclipse.core.resources
```

2) The most common hiccup is when another web server (or any process for that matter) has laid claim to port 8080.  This is the default HTTP port that Tomcat attempts to bind to at start-up.  To change this, open the file:

```
   $CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml
```

And search for '8080'.  Change it to a port that isn't in use, and is greater than 1024, as ports less than or equal to 1024 require superuser access to bind under UNIX. (Example 8181)

Restart Tomcat and you're in business.  Be sure that you replace the **`"8080"`** in the URL you're using to access Tomcat.
  For example, if you **`change the port to 8181`**, you would request the URL http://localhost:8181/ in your browser.

3) Open the bin folder which contains the shutdown.bat file residing inside the tomcat directory. Run it, that should solve the port problem.